# Python Lambda Function Response Structure For App Sync Resolver

Tags: python, graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to get a very simple example working in App Sync in which I will return a hardcoded list and an ID from a query, but I cannot work out what the response from my python lambda should look like. Whatever I try, I end up with `null` values when I run the query.

Here is my schema:

```
type BMSDefinition {
    object_id: String
    definition: String
}

type BMSDefinitions {
    premise_id: ID
    definitions: [BMSDefinition]
}

type Query {
    getDefinitions(premise_id: ID!): BMSDefinitions
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
```

Here is my simple function:

```
import json

def handler(event, context):
  data = json.dumps(get_definitions())
  
  return data
  
def get_definitions():
  return {
    "premise_id":"123456",
    "definitions": [
      {
        "object_id": "123456", 
        "definition": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "object_id": "7891011", 
        "definition": "DEF"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is my query:

```
query MyQuery {
  getDefinitions(premise_id: "123") {
    premise_id
    definitions {
      object_id
      definition
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the result of calling the API:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getDefinitions": {
      "premise_id": null,
      "definitions": null
    }
  }
}
```

The lambda function definitely executes each time I run the query, I can see this from the lambda logs. If I look at the logs for AppSync I can see this in the response section of an execution of the query:

```
"context": {
        "arguments": {
            "installation_id": "123"
        },
        "result": "{\"premise_id\": \"123456\", \"definitions\": [{\"object_id\": \"123456\", \"definition\": \"ABC\"}, {\"object_id\": \"7891011\", \"definition\": \"DEF\"}]}",
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "transformedTemplate": "{\"premise_id\": \"123456\", \"definitions\": [{\"object_id\": \"123456\", \"definition\": \"ABC\"}, {\"object_id\": \"7891011\", \"definition\": \"DEF\"}]}"
```

I have attached the lambda data source to the  `getDefinitions` query in the schema view and I thought that using no VTL and the lambda resolver that AppSync should be mapping the fields in my response to the model in the schema.

I don't really know where to go from here as I cannot see why the values are null.

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of trial and error and looking at the responses in cloudwatch I finally figured out this was the lambda response output. I ended up writing a mapping template to transform the response and instead of getting `null` I then got empty string and array.

The fix was pretty simple, instead of stringifying my response I removed that and it now works:

```
response = {
        "premise_id": premise_id,
        "definitions": definitions
    }
```

I think somewhere there were backslashes being added to the transformed response by AppSync and this was causing the response to then never match the schema model.